# Way to Stack Application Instances in OSX Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I run OSX with tons and tons of application instances; so I am looking for a way to tell OSX to stack application instances in the dock the same way Windows 7 does. (blasphemy, I know) Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you get application instances - the standard Apple way is for one application to deal with many documrnts

Comment: Eg. My dock is full of finder and firefox instances.

Comment: How do you start them as both those give me only one instance if I start them from dock or finder

Comment: LOL, the possibility that the invocation path matters hadn't occurred to me. I see, well if you want the additional windows (at least when using Firefox) you can request a new window via Firefox's file menu.

Comment: But a new window does not open another app instance

Comment: For some reason it does on my machine.  Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried HyperDock (http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/)?  It adds several of Windows 7's task bar features to the OSX Dock, and as a wonderful bonus also enables window snapping (like Aero Snap).